# Passing inline constructed class as a Class argument to a method

Tags: java

I need to call following method.

```
void foo(Class<? extends Bar> cls);
```

For `cls` argument, I need to pass a class that only overrides a single method of `Bar`.

I want to know whether there is a way to write the definition of my new class inline in above call itself without writing a new class in a separate file which extends Bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

- You could create a nested class within the same class you want to use this code; no need for a new file

  ```
  public static void doSomething() {
      foo(Baz.class);
  }

  private static class Baz extends Bar {
      // Override a method
  }
  ```
- You could declare a named class within the method:

  ```
  public static void doSomething() {
      class Baz extends Bar {
          // Override a method
      }
      foo(Baz.class);
  }
  ```

  Declaring a class within a method like this is highly unusual, mind you.
- You could use an anonymous inner class, but then call `getClass()`:

  ```
  public static void doSomething() {
      foo(new Bar() {
          // Override a method
      }.getClass());
  }
  ```

The last option creates an instance of the anonymous inner class *just* to get the `Class` object of course, which isn't ideal.

Personally I'd *probably* go for the first option.

Comment: In above three options, only the first option allowed `foo` to create a new instance by `cls.newInstance()`

Comment: @LahiruChandima: Even when `doSomething` was a static method? Interesting and surprising - I suspect that the compiler was adding a constructor parameter for captured variables even when none was captured.

Comment: I didn't check with a static `doSomething()`. In my case I need to call `foo` in a non static context.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can simply declare an anonymous class and use the `getClass()` method on it:

```
foo(new Bar() {
    //implement your method here
}.getClass());
```